# Calling a jar file from Python using JPype-total newbie query

Tags: python, jar, jpype

So I have been using subprocess.call to run a **jar** file from Python as so:

```
subprocess.call(['java','-jar','jarFile.jar',-a','input_file','output_file'])
```

where it writes the result to an external output_file file. and *-a* is an option.

I now want to analyse output_file in python but want to avoid opening the file again. So I want to run **jarFile.jar** as a Python function, like:

```
output=jarFile(input_file)
```

I have installed JPype and got it working, I have set the class path and started the JVM environment:

```
import jpype

classpath="/home/me/folder/jarFile.jar"

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),"-Djava.class.path=%s"%classpath)
```

and am now stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java -jar jarFile.jar` executes the main method of a class file that is configured in the jar's [manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Main_Attributes).
You find that class name if you extract the jar file's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (open the jar with any zip tool). Look for the value of `Main-Class`. If that's for instance `com.foo.bar.Application` you should be able to call the main method like this

```
def jarFile(input_file):
    # jpype is started as you already did
    assert jpype.isJVMStarted()
    tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    jpype.com.foo.bar.Application.main(['-a', input_file, tf.name])
    return tf
```

(I'm not sure about the correct use of the tempfile module, please check yourself)